# Automizing deeply nested function python

Tags: python

I have a database model with deeply nested children. I am trying to add add all of the underlying ids (of all levels) to a dictionary entry. My current code looks as follows:

```
children = obj.children
    for child in children:
        data["children_ids"].append(child.id)
        for child in child.children:
            data["children_ids"].append(child.id)
            for child in child.children:
                data["children_ids"].append(child.id)
                for child in child.children:
                    data["children_ids"].append(child.id)
```

This code is fully functional, but the problem is fairly obvious. I don't want to keep writing the same code over and over again: it's ugly, impractical and not very maintainable. How would I do this?

Comment: Have you thought about going recursive?

Comment: This doesn't directly address your question, but I'd suggest that the [Visitor pattern](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) might come in useful here. It's about separating the logic for traversing a data structure from the logic to operate on the elements. It's useful when you have different operations on the same structure.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Yeah, I had thought about multiple options, such as using a while loop and going recursive. However, I got none of those to work, hence the question.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Since I'm doing this also to learn Python, I really don't mind it if it doesn't directly address the question. It's really interesting, though quite hard at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a recursive function to run the same code on different children:

```
def add_children_ids(ids, children):
    for child in children:
        ids.append(child.id)
        add_children_ids(ids, child.children)

children = obj.children
data['children_ids'] = []
add_children_ids(data['children_ids'], children)
```

Because `ids` is a mutable list, there's no need to `return` it

Comment: I think `add_children_ids(children, child.children)`, should be `add_children_ids(ids, child.children)`, then it works.

Comment: I got none of these options to work, *initially*. I had thought about going recursive, and about using a while loop, but neither of them would work in my own implementations. The solutions provided in the answers do work.

Answer (score 5):

How about a while loop?

```
children = list(obj.children)
while children:
    child = children.pop()
    data["children_ids"].append(child.id)
    grandchildren = getattr(child, 'children', None)
    if grandchildren:
        children.extend(list(grandchildren))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work: it gets only the first level (just tried it). I had tried something very similar before asking this question and after experimenting with it for half an hour and not being able to figure it out, I asked the question here.

Comment: Can you print out the value of `children` at the end of the loop? Is the `getattr` not working?

Comment: Ah, I see what happened. Edited, try that now.

Comment: As to your question from before the edit: `getattr` was always returning `None`. Your new answer doesn't work because I can't do `children.pop()`, because I can't alter a database object (`AttributeError: 'SelectQuery' object has no attribute 'pop'`)

Comment: Try now - this should copy it to a new list

Comment: If getattr doesn't work, does `children.get('children', None)` work?

Comment: `getattr` indeed still returned `None`; `children.get('children', None)` gives me `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

Comment: Sorry, I meant `child.get('children', None)`

Comment: It still doesn't work. I had to look around a little to get what the error meant, but it basically means that child is still a database instance object, so `get` doesn't work for this.

Comment: What type of object is it? There should be some way to detect if it contains a `.children` attribute, or catch the exception when you try to access it.

Comment: It's a Peewee database instance object. I didn't think that this was relevant at first, since I can just manipulate it in Python like any other object using the for-loop.

Comment: Yes, it works now! Thanks a lot; I learnt a lot from experimenting with this code.